# Create this shape in CSS (half pipe shape)

Tags: css

I've been trying to make this shape in CSS, but unfortunately could not find a way how to. It's half pipe like shaped:

[image]

The pixelated corner should be smooth (it's a zoomed in image).

Anyone knows how to create this? Or can get me on the right tracks?

Comment: That is probably done with border-radius. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: [MDN: `border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use pseudo element `:after` for the inner block and then apply `border-radius` for curved corner.

```css
div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border: solid red;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, did is what did it for me!

Answer (score 1):

simple

```css
.shape {
  width: 140px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.shape:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one element and with transparency like this:

```css
.box {
  width:80px;
  height:100px;
  border-right:20px solid grey;
  border-bottom:20px solid grey;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:
   radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left,transparent 98%,grey ) bottom right/20px 20px no-repeat;
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem here is to create the "outer" curve, on the arbitrary background. It's achievable by [the trick](http://kizu.ru/fun/rounded-inner-corners/) with clipping the needed part from the thick rounded border of the pseudo-element:

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 4em;
  margin: auto;
  border: #888 solid;
  border-width: 0 1em 1em 0;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  border: #888 solid;
  border-width: 0 1em 1em 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1em;
  bottom: -1em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  clip: rect(0 1em 1em 0);
}

div:hover::after {
  border-color: red; /* highlight the curved part */
}

body {
  /* just as a background example */
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ddd, #ddd 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 10px);
  min-height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```